# Electric field from a sheet of charge?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields

Does anyone have images of the electric field created by a **real** plate of charge? I'm not looking for an image of a theoretical infinite sheet of charge, I'm looking for an image of a real large one.

By a real plate, I mean a finite one.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link that allows you to simulate the field lines and equipotentials of both point charges and charged plates:

http://www.falstad.com/emstatic/

Perhaps you will find what you are looking for here.